# CDK + copy encrypted s3 artifacts between cross aws account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, aws-cdk

I have a few ml models trained in dev environment s3. I want to copy that into stage and prod account s3 using cdk.
Previously, I was doing it in cdk synth time using this code[ ***s3 artifacts was not encrypted then***]

```
boto3.resource("s3").meta.client.copy(
        {"Bucket": source_bucket_name, "Key": source_file},
         destination_bucket_name,
         source_file,
     )
```

It worked completely fine. But now AWS s3 by default encrypts every object with the type
`Server-side encryption with AWS Key Management Service keys (SSE-KMS)`

Now my code does not work for encrypted files. It throws an error.
 `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: Access Denied`

Any suggestion?

Update 1: I added this permission to the cdk user/role which did not work.

```
        {
            "Sid": "AllowKMSDecryptFromSourceBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:source-account-key-arn
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowKMSEncryptToDestinationBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:destination-account-key-arn"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: You could change encryption to SSE-S3 (which should be default if you didn't set anything yourself), or you can add KMS permissions to the user/role used for copying

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that to the question. I tried that also, did not work. I just update my question.